# User signed out halfway through cucumber test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cucumber

I'm in the process of splitting change-password functionality off into its own page on my site. The whole process works fine when I run through it manually as a real user, but I can't get my Cucumber tests to pass, the reason being that on the final call to the controller, the current_user is mysteriously returning nil.

I've having a serious WTF moment because the user DEFINITELY is being logged in at the beginning of the tests, and I'm following all the same steps as other passing tests, and as I said the whole thing works fine when stepping through it by hand.

Here's the test in question:

```
Scenario: The user should be able to change their password
  Given I have a signed in user with email = "test@mycompany.com" and password = "password"
  When I am on the change-password page  # this hits registrations_controller#change_password
  And I fill in "Current password" with "password"
  And I fill in "New password" with "new_password"
  And I fill in "Re-enter new password" with "new_password"
  And I press "Update"
  Then I should see "You updated your account successfully"
```

And the login step:

```
Given /^I have a signed in user with email\s*=\s*"([^"]*)" and password\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"$/ do |email, password|
  @user = User.new
  @user.email = email
  @user.password = password
  @user.confirm!
  @user.save!
  visit '/sign_in'
  fill_in("Email", :with => @user.email)
  fill_in("Password", :with => @user.password)
  click_button("Sign in")
end
```

Controller actions, from "registrations_controller.rb":

```
  def change_password
    # calling "current_user" here retuns the logged-in user as expected
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update_password
    # calling "current_user" here returns nil
    # error occurs at call to nil.update_with_password
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_with_password( params["user"] )
      redirect_to after_update_path_for( @user )
    else
      clean_up_passwords( @user )
      render_with_scope :change_password
    end
  end
```

Now, we are using devise (1.1.8), and my best guess is that I've done something wrong with the devise routes, which look like this in "routes.rb"

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:confirmations => "confirmations", :sessions => "sessions", :registrations => "registrations"} do

    # ...other routes here...

    get "/change_password", :to => "registrations#change_password"
    put "/update_password", :to => "registrations#update_password"
  end
```

Finally, for completeness, here is "change_password.html.haml"

```
= render :partial => "shared/stats"

#main
  = form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => "update_password", :html => { :method => :put, :autocomplete => "off" }) do |f|
    = devise_error_messages!
    .edit-account-hold
      %span Your password
      = f.label :current_password, "Current password"
      = f.password_field :current_password
      = f.label :password, "New password"
      = f.password_field :password
      = f.label :password_confirmation, "Re-enter new password"
      = f.password_field :password_confirmation

      = f.submit "Update", :class => "orange-button border-radius"
      = link_to "Cancel", account_path, :id => "cancel-link"

  :javascript
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $("#user_current_password").focus();
    });
```

Comment: Do you have a `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in your controller?

Comment: Hmm, @Gazler, I have the following at the top of the registrations_controller.rb:

`prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create ]
prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]`

I'm not gonna lie, I don't know exactly what these mean. Will investigate...

Comment: `authenticate_scope!` looks like this:

`def authenticate_scope!
    send(:"authenticate_#{resource_name}!");
    self.resource = resource_class.find(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").id);
  end`

Which does indeed resolve to a call to `send(:authenticate_user!)`

When I include `:update_proposal` action in this callback, Cucumber seems to vomit at this call, although it gives me zero information as to why. In the regular development environment, this causes no problems.

P.S. Sorry I can't format this stuff better here...

Comment: It's looking like this might be a red herring. Even at the very beginning of the callbacks, current_user returns the proper user at the call to "#change_password" action, but returns nil at the call to "#update_password" action.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it through Selenium. Watching the test run can often give clues about what's going wrong.